# Delete non-consecutive lines in command mode

Tags: command-line

When I edit some code, I have a repl aside which gives me useless imports/includes, and I'd like to remove them in one command.

To be concrete, I have the following text:

```
import A
import B
import C
import D
import E
import F
import G
```

And I would like to remove lines 1, 3, 4, and 7.

I have tried `:1,3,4,7` but it does not work (because these are ranges). Is there a way to do it in one command?

Comment: If all the lines you want removed include a unique pattern then it might be easier to use ::g/<pattern>/d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
:for i in reverse([1, 3, 4, 7]) | exe i . 'delete' | endfor
```

This could easily be put into a function that could be called:

```
function DeleteLines(lines)
    let lines = reverse(uniq(sort(a:lines, 'n')))
    for i in lines
        if i > line('$')
            echohl WarningMsg
            echomsg "Warning: Line number " . i . " is beyond the end of the file."
            echohl None
            continue
        endif
        exe i . 'delete'
    endfor
endfunction
```

Then you can delete lines specified in any order you like:

```
:call DeleteLines([7, 1, 4, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not really possible. Besides the way @Heptite mention, you can do it in 1 command interactively like this:

```
:%s/^import.*\n//c
```

This will ask for confirmation of the line to be deleted. Adjust the search pattern to taste.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to delete lines 1, 3, 4, and 7 this should do the trick:

```
:g/\v%1l|%3l|%4l|%7l/d
```

This uses the `g` command in vim to find all lines that match the given regex. The regex enables very magic at the beginning ofnthe regex with `\v` making it so that regex branches normally delimited with `\|` can now be delimited with simply `|`, as well as various regex atoms in Vim starting with `%`. Then the regex then uses the `%[n]l` regex atom which matches anywhere on line n. This yields a regex which matches any position on lines 1,3,4, or 7. Then we filter lines with this regex using the `g` command and run `d` to delete them.

However this isn't really ideal because if for some reason there was a new import before import A you'd now be deleting that import and imports B, C, and F, instead of imports A, C, D, and G. For this particular example perhaps something like this would work better:

```
:g/\v^\s*import\s+(A|C|D|G)>
```

Comment: You don’t need to group the first regex, which saves some typing

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Ah, yeah not sure why I had the regex group in there. Thanks for the tip! Updated the answer with it

Comment: I don't like the notation. But this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Bash, Ksh or Zsh shell,

- From inside Vim:

  ```
  :%!sed -e{1,3,4,7}d
  ```
- From the shell itself:

  ```
  sed -e{1,3,4,7}d file
  ```
- Assuming a Sed that supports `-i`, from the shell itself with in-place editing (i.e., the changes are written to the file rather than only being output):

  ```
  sed -ie{1,3,4,7}d file
  ```

If the number of lines you want to keep is smaller than the number of lines to delete, it is better to use

```
sed -ne{2,5,6}p file
```